# extracting a value from a JSON string

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I'm working on a Blazor application and I have a Json string from which I'm trying to extract a value.

Json Data looks like this:

```
{"a1":"a1234","e1":"e1234}
```

I'm trying to extract the `a1` value from this which is `"a1234"`

My JSON Data is in a string variable, `rawJsonData`. I'm trying to use the JsonSerializer.Deserialize, but I'm not sure how to completely use it...

```
@code 
{
    string rawJsonData = JsonData (this is not the actual data, it's being pulled from elsewhere)
    var x = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<???>(rawJsonData)
}
```

is this the right way to approach this? I'm not sure what to put in place of ??? above. Anyone has experience with this.

Comment: you can create a class that represents that... or use the jsondocument way.

Comment: Make sure that the json is valid, you are missing an ending "" fyi

Comment: If you only need one value you can parse the json and dig out that one value.  no need for a class that way.  Gobs and gobs of posts here on both deserializing and parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Newtonsoft, as suggested in another answer, you don't even have to create a class.

```
JObject temp = JObject.Parse(rawJsonData);
var a1 = temp["a1"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class:

```
public class Root
{
   public string a1 { get; set; }
   public string e1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then `Deserialize` it into that class:

```
var x = System.Text.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(rawJsonData);
```

Or use Newtonsoft.Json:

```
var x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(rawJsonData);
```

To retrieve the value of `a1` just call: `x.a1`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with System.Text.Json and don't want to create a class/struct for the data (why not?), as suggested in comments, you can

```cs
var jsonData = "{\"a1\":\"a1234\",\"e1\":\"e1234\"}";
var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonData);
var a1 = doc?.RootElement.GetProperty("a1").GetString();
```

Of course, a try catch around the conversion would help.